# Slowly download of Audio using YoutubeExploid C#

Tags: c#

Please tell me what the problem might be. I use YoutubeExploide to download Audio but it downloads very slowly and when I download videos it is fast.

```cs
private async Task<bool> DownloadYouTubeVideo(DownloadItem downloadItem)
{
    var youtube = new YoutubeClient();
    var video = await youtube.Videos.GetAsync(downloadItem.UrlId);
  
    string sanitizedTitle = string.Join("_",video.Title.Split(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));

    var streamManifest = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync(video.Id);
    var audioStream = streamManifest.GetAudioOnlyStreams().OrderByDescending(s => s.Bitrate).ToList();

    if (audioStream.Any())
    {
        var streamInfo = audioStream .First();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(streamInfo.Url);

        string fileName = GetFileName(downloadItem);
        var musicLib = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        var folder = await musicLib.CreateFolderAsync(downloadFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);


        IOutputStream outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(stream.AsInputStream(), outputStream);
        OpenDownloadsFolderButton_Click();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using HttpClient wrong. Also: could it be due to the need to decode and reencode audio as opposed to just download the video data? Or is the audio stream prepared and ready for download? How do you measure download speed?

Comment: Do you know of any restrictions of the api itself? Could it be throttled?

Comment: Audio is not prepared, there only videos, but i think it converts when downloading. 1mb of audio can downloads 20 seconds.

Comment: Well, there you have it. Transcoding comes with an overhead.

Comment: I try use FFmpeg for convert video in audio, but in uwp app i have exception access denied.